# Rspec feature test to check that the right i18n content is used when user connects from certain countries (rails 4, geocoder, rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rails-geocoder

I am using in my Rails app a feature that detects thanks to geocoder the country from where th user connects then I serve the content based on that.

I'd like to create rspec features tests to be sure for example that

- if a German used connects from France, he sees "Bonjour cher utilisateur" (from the fr.yml file)
- if a German used connects from France, he sees "Hi dear user" (from the en.yml file)

**I've tried to check on the web how to "stub" or "mock" this, but i don't know how to do that (still a newbie).
That's what I have tried but it fails:**

```
 describe "the right locale is generated when user visits homepage from the US" do
     request.location.country= 'US'
     visit root_path
     expect(page).to have_content 'Hi dear user'       
end
```

Here are files enabling me to geolocate and serve the right language

controllers/concerns/CountrySetter

```
def set_location_by_ip_lookup  

    if Rails.env.development?
      Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first
    else
      request.location
    end
  end
```

controller/concerns/LocaleSetter

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_country
  end

def extract_locale_from_country

  case I18nData.country_code(set_location_by_ip_lookup.country)
      # codes here https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search
      when 'US'
        'en'
      when 'FR'
        'fr'
      when 'ES'
        'es'
      when 'DE'
        'de'
      when 'NL'
        'nl'
      else
        'en'
    end
  end
```

EDIT

I tried

```
describe "A connection from an IP located in Germany triggers country=Germany (used in LocaleSetter and CountrySetter) " do

    let(:subject) { ApplicationController.new } 

    it "loads the right locale on the HP" do
      allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:remote_ip) {'77.185.208.234'}

      subject.class.skip_before_filter :set_location_by_ip_lookup
      subject.class.skip_before_filter :set_locale

      expect(request.location.country).to eq("Germany")

    end

  end
```

And I am getting the error:

```
ApplicationController A connection from an IP located in Germany triggers country=Germany (used in LocaleSetter and CountrySetter)  loads the right locale on the HP
     Failure/Error: expect(request.location.country).to eq("Germany")

       expected: "Germany"
            got: "Reserved"

       (compared using ==)

Finished in 0.22149 seconds (files took 24 minutes 5 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:10
```

It seems based on another question I had actually, that geocoder returns "reserved" when ip is treated as local (127.0.0 or 00.0.00.0) : see [Geocoder Gem - getting "Reserved" for request.location.country (even in Local!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216883/geocoder-gem-getting-reserved-for-request-location-country-even-in-local)

So it seems rspec does not understand I am trying to give him remote_ip = 77.185.208.234

Answer (score 1):

`visit` is a capybara method, which is starting a browser driver and therefore has an extra session in a separate thread. Because of it, it cannot see this rack request instance, but creates a separate one.

In a feature spec you will have to stub `any_instance` of the rack request. You can stub the location method (coming from geocoder) to return `Geocoder::Result` like this:

```
#rspec 3 syntax    
allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:location) do 
   instance_double("Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip", :country => 'United States')  
end
```

And actually you don't have to test the whole country logic in a feature spec. I most cases you can just rely on Rails I18n to work correctly once it was properly set and configured. I would test the :set_locale logic in a controller/request spec separtely and just check the I18n.locale. In request spec, there is no capybara session and you will have a direct access to the controller instance or it's request

```
 #spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb
 describe ApplicationController do

   describe "GET index" do

     it "sets location by ip lookup" do
        allow(request).to recieve(:location)do 
          instance_double("Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip", :country => 'United States') 
        end
        get "index"
        expect(I18n.locale).to eq 'en'
     end

   end
 end
```

NOTE:

Geocoder has also a country_code method for most providers.

instead of

```
  I18nData.country_code(set_location_by_ip_lookup.country)
```

use

```
  set_location_by_ip_lookup.country_code
```

and stub that accordingly in the tests

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think you're totally right i just have to test i18n in rspec/features and move to controller the other tests. However, I tried to implement what you advice and am getting an error => see EDIT on my post

Comment: I've reconsidered my previous answer and edited it. It would be not a good idea to ask geocoder for ip lookups, because it's using external providers and one should not rely on external api's when writing tests. Also there is just no need to test anything the geocoder creators have already tested. Examine your edited code, it's not testing anything of your logic, ip lookups will work correctly, if not, file up an issue on geocoder github project. What you want to test is, wether an ip lookup will start on visiting the index page and set the correct locale according to a proper geocoder result